# Building a docker image from dockerfile, can't get java to run correctly, but can run java from image as command line parameters in docker run command

Tags: java, docker, dockerfile

I am new to docker and dockerfile files, having just started trying to write them. I have built a simple java console application and can successfully build a docker image from a dockerfile, but if I include

```
CMD ["java","-jar","app.jar"]
```

when I try to run the image I always get a bin/sh error, typically "java not found" or the like.

However, when I don't include the CMD line and just use this Dockerfile to build my image

```
FROM openjdk:8-jre-alpine
COPY app.jar /app.jar
```

and then run

```
docker run -it --rm my-container:tag
```

I can then run

```
java -jar app.jar
```

and the application runs as expected.

I can also run

```
docker run -it --rm my-container:tag java -jar app.jar
```

and the application runs as expected.

Every guide I read says I should be able to use CMD or ENTRYPOINT as written above, but nothing ever works.

What might I be missing in this simple example?

Thank you,
Trevor

EDIT: I am running docker version 18.06.1-ce-mac73 (26764) on MacOS Sierra. I am not positive that docker works this way, but I have two image versions in my public docker hub. The dockerfile for v1 is:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jre-alpine
COPY 454calendar.jar app.jar
```

The dockerfile for v2 is:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jre-alpine
ENV PROJECT_DIR=/app
WORKDIR $PROJECT_DIR
COPY 454calendar.jar $PROJECT_DIR
```

If I add

```
CMD [“java”,”-jar”,”454calendar.jar”]
```

to the v2 dockerfile and rebuild, I get this error with the docker run command.

```
/bin/sh: [“java”,”-jar”,”454calendar.jar”]: not found
```

Without the CMD line, I can run container and it starts right into the /app working directory where I can run the java command and execute the program.

The two versions of the container in my public docker repository do not have the CMD line in their respective dockerfiles.

Comment: What version of docker are you running ?

Comment: I have tried with your image, no error occurred. So you’d better add the specific error message you got, it seems the most important part.

Comment: Can you include your `Dockerfile` please? It seems like a missing `WORKDIR` configuration to me.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was maddeningly simple. Thanks to [@Rakesh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10479286/rakesh), I checked the configuration for TextEdit on MacOS and saw that Smart Quotes was turned on. Once I turned off that option and retyped the double quotes, then rebuilt and ran the docker container, the application started up just as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any problem with your approach. I was able to make a `HelloWorld` application to run with the below `Dockerfile`.

```
FROM openjdk:8-jre-alpine
RUN mkdir /app
RUN cd /app
COPY HelloWorld.jar /app/HelloWorld.jar
WORKDIR /app
CMD ["java","-jar", "HelloWorld.jar"]
```

I'm on the following docker version

```
docker -v
Docker version 18.06.1-ce, build e68fc7a

docker-compose -v
docker-compose version 1.22.0, build f46880f
```

Comment: There must be something wrong with my configuration or something. I wrote the exact same dockerfile (changing the .jar file name only) and I just get this every time I try to run the container: /bin/sh: [“java”,”-jar”,”454calendar.jar”]: not found

Comment: @Trevor are you sure you have the right double code symbols on your docket file?

Comment: @ Rakesh: You know, the double quotes in TextEdit do look funny; I'm going to try a different text editor. My exact run command is: docker run -it --rm tdawg206/454calendar:v2

Comment: @ Rakesh: The quotes were the problem. MacOS TextEdit application had Smart Quotes enabled, so they kept changing. Once I turned that off and retyped the double quotes, then rebuilt and ran the container, it worked exactly as expected! Thank you for triggering me to check for that.

Comment: FROM openjdk:8-jre-alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY HelloWorld.jar HelloWorld.jar
CMD ["java","-jar", "HelloWorld.jar"]